# EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN error when running on a device

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, automatic-ref-counting

Why is this code running on the simulator and crashing on a real device?

I have a very simple code that draws a circle. The code subclasses `UIView` and runs fine on the Simulator (both for iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.0).

**Circle.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Circle : UIView

@end
```

**Circle.m**

```
#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle

-(CGPathRef) circlePath{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:10.0 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:360.0 clockwise:YES];
    return path.CGPath;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPathRef circle = [self circlePath];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddPath( ctx, circle );
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}

@end
```

When I try to execute the code on an iPad2 running iOS 5.1.1 I get an error ( `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN,address=0x31459241)` ) on the `CGContextAddPath( ctx, circle );` line.

I have not a clue of what the problem is. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `CGPath` you are returning is owned by the autoreleased `UIBezierPath` created in the `circlePath` method. By the time you are adding the path object the `UIBezierPath` has been released, so the returned pointer is pointing to invalid memory. You can fix the crash by returning the `UIBezierPath` itself:

```
-(UIBezierPath *)circlePath {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path addArcWithCenter:self.center radius:10.0 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:360.0 clockwise:YES];
    return path;
}
```

Then draw using:

```
CGContextAddPath( ctx, circle.CGPath );
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. I don't get one thing though, why did my code run on the simulator? The CGPath should have been released as well, am I wrong?

Comment: @Xavi the i386 instruction set is much less finicky than ARM.  The simulator is never a good benchmark of actual performance on a device anyhow.