# Crash using [UIBezierPath CGPath] with CAShapeLayer under ARC

Tags: ios, core-animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm getting a BAD ACCESS error using `[UIBezierPath CGPath]` with `CAShapeLayer` under ARC. I've tried bridging in various ways but I'm not clear if that is the problem. I have isolated the crash to using the result of the `makeToPath` method:

```
 maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 maskLayer.path = [self makeToPath];
```

But this doesn't crash:

```
 maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 maskLayer.path = [self makeFromPath];
```

Is there something invalid with the path created by `makeToPath`? I'm planning to use the *from* and *to* paths with a `CABasicAnimation` once I sort this crash out. What is the correct ARC bridging for `CGPathRef`s from `UIBezierPath`?

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath
{
    UIBezierPath* triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [triangle moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0)];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [triangle closePath];
    return [triangle CGPath];
}

-(CGPathRef)makeFromPath
{
    UIBezierPath*rect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.frame];
    return [rect CGPath];
}
```

**UPDATE** So I changed my .h file per an answer below but I am still getting the crash

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
-(CGPathRef)makeFromPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

I also tried making my methods return a `UIBezierPath` instance per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14130159/840992) (shown below). Still no success. Anyone want to give me the longform explanation on how to fix this?

```
maskLayer.path = [[self makeToPath] CGPath];// CRASHES
morph.toValue =  CFBridgingRelease([[self makeToPath] CGPath]);// CRASHES
```

---

```
-(UIBezierPath*)makeToPath
{
    UIBezierPath* triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [triangle moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0)];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [triangle closePath];
    return triangle;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_ARM\_DA\_ALIGN error when running on a device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129785/exc-arm-da-align-error-when-running-on-a-device)

Comment: I use that final syntax, having `makeToPath` return `UIBezierPath *` and then using `maskLayer.path = [[self makeToPath] CGPath];`, all the time. But I'm also immediately using `maskLayer`, e.g. `[self.view.layer addSublayer:maskLayer]`. What are you doing with `maskLayer` after setting its `path`? Can you show us?

Comment: @Rob - I cleaned up some code, ran the `nap debugger` and now it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with returning the CGPath. The value returned is a CGPathRef which is not covered by ARC. The `UIBezierPath` you create is released after the method ends. Thus also freeing the CGPathRef. 
You can specify a source annotation to let ARC know your intent:

In the .h file:

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
-(CGPathRef)makeFromPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

Comment: thanks - I'm not getting the crash with the method using the `bezierPathWithRect` function. That's confusing. Do you know why that approach doesn't crash?

Comment: Huh. I didn't know those annotations were usable yet. That's awesome, thanks! (Docs are here, for the curious: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-to-retainable-object-pointer-type-of-expressions-with-known-semantics)

Comment: @skinnyTOD: The behavior accessing a released object is undefined.

Comment: ARC does not manage CF objects. How would adding a qualifier to the method have any effect on memory management?

Comment: @DuncanC - it doesn't.  adding these qualifiers had no effect on crashes i am experiencing.

Answer (score 3):

As the other poster pointed out, you are returning a CGPath reference taken from a UIBezierPath object that goes out of scope at the end of the method. As the docs on the UIBezierPath CGPath property say:

> The path object itself is owned by the UIBezierPath object and is
>   valid only until you make further modifications to the path.

You need to create a copy of your CGPath and return that:

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath
{
    UIBezierPath* triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [triangle moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0)];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [triangle closePath];
    CGPathRef theCGPath = [triangle CGPath];
    return CGPathCreateCopy(theCGPath);
}
```

The way I read the link to the llvm project, I think that the cf_returns_retained qualifier is intended to tell the caller the memory management policy for the returned value, rather than doing the retain for you.

Thus I think you would both need to create a copy of the path AND add the cf_returns_retained qualifier. I'm not clear on the syntax of that qualifier, however. (Never used it before.)

Assuming the other poster had the right syntax, it would look something like this:

```
-(CGPathRef)makeToPath CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
{
    UIBezierPath* triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [triangle moveToPoint:CGPointZero];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0)];
    [triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [triangle closePath];
    CGPathRef theCGPath = [triangle CGPath];
    return CGPathCreateCopy(theCGPath);
}
```

Comment: The CF_RETURNS_RETAINED annotation is actually only needed if your method doesn't conform to the [CoreFoundation naming rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). It's recommended to rename your methods instead.