# How to encode UIBezierPath to SVG?

Tags: ios, svg, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a simple view for finger painting / drawing. I store the drawings as `UIBezierPath`s in a `NSMutableArray`. Now I want to transfer the drawings to a web-service for presenting them in a browser. Therefore I need to encode my `UIBezierPath`s in a SVG-file - because this the format of the web-service.

What I found right now is the [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/tree/2013base/Source/UIKit%20additions), which only DECODES SVG. Do anybody know sample code, snippets or a framework for encoding SVG?

Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem but for NSBezierPath, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334815/turn-a-bezierpath-into-an-svg-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested yet. but using following steps: Would not it be possible?

1.UIBezierPath to CGPathRef. [UIBezierPath to CGPathRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466313/crash-using-uibezierpath-cgpath-with-cashapelayer-under-arc)

2.Using a [MROGeometry](https://github.com/mro/MROGeometry) CGPathRef To SVG.

Comment: was still a way to go - but it works - and I´m happy :)
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to do step 2? I don't really understand how to do this given the documentation for MROGeometry...