# Turn a BezierPath into an SVG file

Tags: macos, svg, nsbezierpath

I have a NSBezierPath produced from code below, and I want to turn this path into a svg file (see the svg code below) that I can import into Adobe Illustrator. Any ideas how to do this?

> BezierPath description

```
NSColor* color0 = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 0 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 1];

{
    //// Bezier Drawing
    NSBezierPath* bezierPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(2, 30.41)];
    [bezierPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(8.41, 1.91) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(5.73, 41.21) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(17.37, 63.33)];
    [bezierPath curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(49.79, 1.53) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(45.32, 94.95) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(41.89, 1.26)];
    [bezierPath setMiterLimit: 4];
    [bezierPath setLineCapStyle: NSRoundLineCapStyle];
    [bezierPath setLineJoinStyle: NSRoundLineJoinStyle];
    [color0 setStroke];
    [bezierPath setLineWidth: 3];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

> svg description

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="n1">
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M2,169.585
        c3.73-10.794,15.369-32.913,6.406,28.508c36.91-93.04,33.489,0.644,41.384,0.381"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

> Some observations

BezierPath uses [NSBezierPath bezierPath] to indicate start of path data while svg use d = "path data".

BezierPath uses moveToPoint while svg uses M.

BezierPath uses curveToPoint while svg uses c.

svg does not use spaces, but instead uses a very compact form.

BezierPath uses absolute coordinates while svg uses relative coordinates.

For curves BezierPath uses the order "point, controlPoint1, controlPoint2" while svg uses the order "controlPoint1, controlPoint2, point".

Observe that we are embedding the path into a box of width="200px" height="200px" in svg.

Using these observations we could translate BezierPath description into svg description as follows:

1. moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(2, 30.41)]

is translated into M2,169.59   (M=MoveToPoint, 2=2, 200-30.41=169.59)

2. curveToPoint: NSMakePoint(8.41, 1.91) controlPoint1: NSMakePoint(5.73, 41.21) controlPoint2: NSMakePoint(17.37, 63.33)]

is translated into

c3.73-10.794,15.369-32.913,6.406,28.508

(c=curveToPoint, 3.73=5.73-2, -10.8=30.41-41.21, 15.37=17.37-2, 32.89=63.3-30.41, 6.41=8.41-2, 28.5=30.41-1.91))

and so on

I guess I could use these observations to make my own translations, but it would be nicer and more general if there was already written code that I could use.

Comment: SVG can use absolute co-ordinates, simply use C rather than c

Comment: Thanks robert very useful :)

Comment: Using Robert Longson tip about absolute coordinates we get d="M2,169.59
  C5.73,158.79,17.37,136.67,8.41,198.09C45.32,105.05,41.89,198.74,49.79,198.47" which is almost the same as BezierPath coordinates except that we have to flip y coordinate by taking 200-bezierY

Comment: Here's some code to traverse an UI/NSBezierPath and visit each node, if you look at `ILCGPathDescription` you'll see an example of printing the points on a path: https://github.com/alfwatt/KitBridge/blob/master/ILBezierPath%2BKitBridge.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that solves my problem. But it only works for Bezier paths. Observe that I am only filling out the path data. This has to be preceded with some static text of type below. If anybody has a more general or nicer solution, I would like to hear it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 ...
stroke-linejoin="round
```

Observe also that I am using a canvas which is 200x200 (hence 200 when flipping y coordinates).

```
-(NSString *)svgFromBezierPath:(NSBezierPath *)path {
    int numElements = (int) [path elementCount];
    if (numElements == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *result = @"d=\"";
    NSPoint points[3];
    NSString *xStr;
    NSString *yStr;
    NSString *xCp1;
    NSString *yCp1;
    NSString *xCp2;
    NSString *yCp2;
    NSString *temp;
    double yValue;

    for (int i=0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        switch ([path elementAtIndex:i associatedPoints:points])
        {
            case NSMoveToBezierPathElement:
                xStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", points[0].x];
                yValue = 200 - points[0].y;
                yStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", yValue];

                temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"M%@,%@,",xStr, yStr];
                result = [result stringByAppendingString:temp];
                break;

            case NSLineToBezierPathElement:
                xStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", points[0].x];
                yValue = 200 - points[0].y;
                yStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", yValue];

                temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"L%@,%@,",xStr, yStr];
                result = [result stringByAppendingString:temp];
                break;

            case NSCurveToBezierPathElement:
                xStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", points[0].x];
                yValue = 200 - points[0].y;
                yStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", yValue];

                xCp1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", points[1].x];
                yValue = 200 - points[1].y;
                yCp1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", yValue];

                xCp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", points[2].x];
                yValue = 200 - points[2].y;
                yCp2= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", yValue];

                temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"C%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,", xStr, yStr, xCp1, yCp1,xCp2, yCp2];
                result = [result stringByAppendingString:temp];
                break;

            case NSClosePathBezierPathElement:
                result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"z,"];
                break;
        }
    }

    result = [result substringToIndex:result.length-1]; // delete the trailing comma
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"\"/></svg>"];
    return result;
}
```